# ImportError: No module named zope.interface

Tags: iphone, python, ios

I am trying to run server for iphone using http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

My machine is mac 10.6.8
Python version : 2.7.3
I dont have any knowledge regarding python.
i have installed Twisted-12.1.0 additionally but still i am getting this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatserver.py", line 1, in 
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 15, in 
    from zope.interface import implements
ImportError: No module named zope.interface

later i have downloaded zope.app.wsgi-3.15.0 4 but i dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that an `__init__.py` file is not present under zope directory so this directory is not scanned for imports.

Creating a blank `__init__.py` file under zope directory will do the trick.

I solved this error in UNIX by browsing to the zope directory by executing:

```
$touch __init__.py
```

I can confirm that this works also with virtualenv pip installation of zope interface

Comment: This, and this only, solved the "import zope.interface ImportError: No module named interface" error for me. I never would have been able to decipher that out of the stacktrace. Is a solution on linux, too. Upvoted.

Comment: Thought python3 did away with __init__ files.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a [solution](http://anibalpacheco.com/?p=51)

It says that installing a zope module through pip breaks your zope installation because pip installs it in another directory other than the original zope module directory.

From the link

> After install a zope module using pip, for example z3c.password your
>   zope installation gets broken.
>
> This is because pip have installed the module in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/zope and the original module
>   zope.interface is in /usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/ and has minor
>   relevance when importing.

What worked for me is (also given in the link):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope 
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/
```

Comment: Can confirm this works.  Just locate where the python-zope.interface package has installed the zope/interface folder and ln -s to it

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head you can use easy_install for this.

You will need the python-setuptools then you should be able to use

```
easy_install zope.interface
```

If I remember correctly however twisted should be installed as part of OS X python install. Do a quick Google for installing zope.interface for Mac OS X. As twisted is such a widely used library there is plenty of information out there.

Comment: This does not work for me.  There's more going on that might have to do with users' path.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me from downgrading from Python 2.7.3 to 2.7.0!