# ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, twisted, zope.interface

I am trying to build a web scraper (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/intro/tutorial.html#intro-tutorial), but when I am trying to launch the crawler, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/anaconda/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from twisted import version as _txv
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    _checkRequirements()
  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/__init__.py", line 37, in _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface.
```

I checked my installations with pip freeze, and it seems that I have it installed:

```
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Are you certain that `pip` is part of the Anaconda installation and not another Python installation?

Comment: yes, I have it in the anaconda folder.

Comment: But is that the one executed when used without a path? What does `which pip` say is used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named zope.interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010412/importerror-no-module-named-zope-interface)

Comment: $ which pip
/Applications/anaconda/bin/pip

Comment: `code`$ which pip /Applications/anaconda/bin/pip
/Applications/anaconda/bin/pip
/Applications/anaconda/bin/pip`code`