# Problems installing Android sdk on python

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So far, I have installed Android SDK and I'm taking my simple dodger and converting it to Android, but when I run this command on cmd '`python C:\pgs4a\android.py installsdk`' it complains with this error

```
File "C:\pgs4a\android.py", line 10, in <module>
    import rapt.interface as interface
ImportError: No module named rapt.interface
```

' I have no idea what's going on, Could somebody pleease help me? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010412/importerror-no-module-named-zope-interface : You could try installing rapt.interface similarly

Comment: When I run the easy_install command to install rapt.interface I get an invalid syntax error on the python command line, What am I doing wrong? Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Do you have python setup tools installed? If not, download a relevant file for your OS from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools. easy_install works with python setup tools

Comment: The link is dead, any download link for rapt.interface?